# Is Wanda Maximoff related to Quicksilver in Dark Phoenix?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, x-men-cinematic-universe, wandavision, scarlet-witch

In the movie, *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, new characters are introduced that start off as the antagonists, but later on in the story they become protagonists. These character are: Wanda and Pietro Maximoff.

I was watching *WandaVison* and in one of the episodes, Wanda opens the door to find her brother, Pietro, at the door. Pietro died in *Age of Ultron*, and her so called, "brother" that knocked on her door, looks completely different from the last movie. I realized that this is the same guy from *X-Men: Dark Phoenix*.

Here is a picture for anyone who doesn't know who I'm talking about:

[image: Pietro]

These are both Marvel movies, so it makes me think. Is the Pietro in *Dark Phoenix* the same one who is related to Wanda in *WandaVision*? And if so, why don't we see Wanda in the *X-Men* movies?

Comment: “I realized that this is the same guy from X-Men: Dark Phoenix” — Kathryn Hahn was in Dark Phoenix?!?

Comment: Wanda is in the X-Men movies. It's either _First Class_ or _Days of Future Past_, but there's a scene at Quicksilver's house where he shouts to his sister off screen.

Answer (score 5):

It’s not the same person, the one who shows up in *WandaVision* isn’t even Pietro but someone that Agatha was controlling.

> **Monica:** Monica: Agnes doesn't live here. You do.
>
> **Ralph (Pietro):** Oh.
>
> **Monica:** You're Ralph Bohner?
>
> <sub>*WandaVision*, Season 1 Episode 9, “The Season Finale”</sub>

Wanda’s brother in the MCU is the Pietro we see in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* who died. There’s no further relation to the X-Men Cinematic Universe, it was just an Easter Egg and to throw people in the wrong direction.

Comment: "just an Easter Egg and to throw people in the wrong direction". I will be cynical and assume that they cast an actor, for no plot-reason, but only because they knew his appearance will go viral and provide cheap advertisement for the show

Comment: @Taladris: I think there's a bit more to it than pure stunt-casting for the sake of it. WandaVision is one of the MCU's first full forays into television, and it features Wanda creating a real-life TV show, so it's already got a bunch of meta stuff going on. It also already features another of Wanda's loved-ones seemingly brought back from the dead in a way that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite "*WandaVision is one of the MCU's first full forays into television*" - really? So you are not counting "Agents of SHIELD" or "Agent Carter"? They are in the same universe. The movies don't acknowledge the TV shows, but the TV shows make references to the movies

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I’m not! They’re great, and part of the universe, but they had different creative teams and business divisions in charge of them than the movies, so I don’t count them as a “full” foray. Whereas WandaVision’s show runner was Jac Schaeffer, who co-wrote Captain Marvel and Black Widow, and Disney Studios is in charge of the Disney Plus shows and the movies.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite-I'll give you Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. maybe not being canon, but Agent Carter surely is. They even brought back the version of Jarvis from that show in Endgame.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the Pietro in *Dark Phoenix* the same one who is related to Wanda in *WandaVision*?

No. It is the same actor (Evan Peters), but a different character, as the Marvel Cinematic Universe and the X-Men Cinematic Universe are still separate (so far).

In *WandaVision*, his appearance is an Easter egg for fans, but in-universe he is a creation of Agnes to mess with Wanda. There is even a line in the episode of how the agents working outside of Westview notice that the MCU's Pietro from *Age of Ultron* was "re-cast" in Wanda's made-up reality:

> Darcy Lewis: "She recast Pietro?”